# Is the elemental ray spell-like subject to spell resistance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer, spell-resistance

One of my players is using an acid elemental ray against a creature with [spell resistance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#spell-resistance).

There is nothing in the [elemental ray](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/sorcerer.html#elemental) or the [acidic ray](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/sorcerer.html#aberrant) that suggests whether spell resistance applies or not. Other ray spells like [scorching ray](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/scorchingRay.html) or [ray of frost](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/rayOfFrost.html) apply spell resistance, but most acid spells do not, like [acid splash](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/acidSplash.html) or [acid arrow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/acidArrow.html). Thus, I am confused whether spell resistance should apply or not.

The [spell-like](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#spell-like-abilities-sp) entry seems to suggest all spell-likes are subject to spell resistance, but I do not know how well that applies to spell-likes directly based in existing spells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, they are affected by spell resistance

Even though those spell-like abilities, elemental ray and acidic ray, have no spell to base themselves on, spells (in general) and [spell-like abilities](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#spell-like-abilities-sp) are subject to [spell resistance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#spell-resistance), unless otherwise noted.

Spells from the conjuration school can mostly ignore spell resistance, and spell-like abilities based on those spells follow the same rules. So a spell-like ability that duplicates [Create Pit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-pit/), which ignores spell resistance, would also ignore spell resistance. This can be seen on the topic [When Spell Resistance Applies](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#When%20Spell%20Resistance%20Applies):

> Effect Spells: Most effect spells summon or create something and are not subject to spell resistance. Sometimes, however, spell resistance applies to effect spells, usually to those that act upon a creature more or less directly, such as web.

But spell-like abilities that do not duplicate a spell (like elemental ray and acidic ray) follow a more general rule, with their spell level based on the highest spell the character can cast, as per [this FAQ on SLA](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o6x)'s:

> *Cleric domains, sorcerer bloodlines, wizard schools, and certain other class features give spell-like abilities that aren't based on spells. What's the effective spell level for these abilities?*
>
> The effective spell level for these spell-like abilities is equal to the highest-level spell that a character of that class could normally cast at the level the ability is gained.
>
> For example, a 1st-level elemental bloodline sorcerer has **elemental ray** as a spell-like ability. Because a sorcerer 1's highest-level spell available is 1st, that spell-like ability counts as a 1st-level spell. A 9th-level elemental bloodline sorcerer has elemental blast as a spell-like ability. Because a sorcerer 9's highest-level spell available is 4th, that spell-like ability counts as a 4th-level spell.

Comment: +1ed! That FAQ answer was *exactly* what I couldn't find when researching an answer to this question. Nicely done. Man, I wish *3.5* had a rule like this. (It's all *Just compare it to an existing spell!*)

Answer (score 3):

*Elemental Ray* or *Acidic Ray* are spell-like abilities, and thus according to the table you have shown, **they are affected by spell resistance.**

Just because they are similar to another spell does not mean they have any relation in mechanics.

Comment: Thus an acid arrow spell-like will also apply spell resistance?